# S3 redirect to codebuild badge with x-amz-website-redirect-location header

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, svg, amazon-s3, http-status-code-302

I would like to place an object in my s3 bucket which will redirect to my codebuild badge.

I get the codebuild badge with the command:

```sh
CODEBUILD_BADGE_URL=$(\
  aws codebuild batch-get-projects \
    --name Push \
    --query "projects[0].badge.badgeRequestUrl" \
    --output text \
)
```

Next, I get the `unknown.svg` badge in case my codebuild badge url changes and set the object `--metadata` to configure the `website-redirect-location`.

My attempt at doing this is:

```sh
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/codefactory-us-east-1-prod-default-build-badges/unknown.svg > ./badge.svg
aws s3 cp ./badge.svg s3://example.com/badge --metadata "Website-Redirect-Location=$CODEBUILD_BADGE_URL"
```

I also added this metadata, just incase the above was wrong:

```sh
aws s3 cp ./badge.svg s3://example.com/badge --website-redirect $CODEBUILD_BADGE_URL
```

When I visit: http://example.com/badge or https://s3.amazonaws.com/example.com/badge, I just get the `unknown.svg` badge.

The request has the following response headers:

```
x-amz-meta-website-redirect-location: https://codebuild.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/badges?uuid=eyJlbmlong%3D&branch=master
x-amz-request-id: D83EBREQUESTID
x-amz-website-redirect-location: https://codebuild.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/badges?uuid=eyJlbmlong%3D&branch=master
```

and a 200 response code.

My example.com bucket properties has `Static website hosting` configured to `Bucket hosting`.

How can I configure this object to instead redirect to the desired codebuild url? Is this a reasonable approach to solve this type of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after waiting a day or so, I only needed:

```sh
aws s3 cp ./badge.svg s3://example.com/badge --metadata "Website-Redirect-Location=$CODEBUILD_BADGE_URL"
```

no need for `--website-redirect`